# Python / scapy: sniff() function doesn't interrupt when pressing CTRL-C

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, wifi, scapy

I'm working on a script that shows all available WiFi networks. I'm using `scapy` to do so.

I want to end the script when pressing CTRL-C. But after pressing nothing happens and the script continues searching for WiFi networks.

I've read that it could be caused by `threading`. But I'm not starting a single thread. Even after pressing CTRL-BREAK the program continues.

```
def PcktHandler(pckt):
    global APs
    try:
        if pckt.haslayer(Dot11):
            if pckt.type == 0 and pckt.subtype == 8:
                if pckt.addr2 not in APs:
                    APs[pckt.addr2] = pckt.info
                    output_aps(pckt.addr2, pckt.info, on_channel)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os._exit

def output_aps(bssid, essid, channel):

        ch_space = 3
        if len(str(channel)) == 1:
            ch_space = 4

        print(str(bssid).upper()+' '*3+'| '+str(channel)+' '*ch_space+'| '+str(essid))

# scanning for networks   
def scan():
    global on_channel #-> channel currently on

    print('[*] Scanning for WiFi-Networks...\n')
    print('BSSID' + ' '*17 + 'CH' + ' '*5 + 'ESSID')

    while on_channel < 15:
        # channel hopping and sniffing
        try:
            os.system('iwconfig ' + iface + ' channel ' + str(on_channel))
        except (OSError):
            print('[-] Invalid interface.')
        try:
            sniff(iface='wlan0mon', prn=PcktHandler, count=10, timeout=3)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            os._exit

        on_channel += 1
        if on_channel >= 14:
            on_channel = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = argument_parser()
    APs = {}
    on_channel = 1

    if args.interface:
        iface = args.interface
        conf.iface = iface

        if args.scan:
            scan()


    else:
        print('[!] Select an interface.')
```

Hopefully there is a solution!
Thank you for helping!

Comment: Why are you *catching the KeyboardInterrupt*? (`os._exit` also isn't actually calling the function, and `os._exit` is most likely not even the right function to call, but first, why are you catching KeyboardInterrupt?)

Comment: It didn't work without the exception so I added it to see a result. I don't know if this is the right way to do so..